# OpenQuery for SQL Query

Tags: oracle11g, sql-server-2012, openquery

Kindly help me writing below query in openquery.Thanks in advance

```
 INSERT INTO  Tablename

    SELECT * FROM tablename1 WHERE insertionorderid IN (

    SELECT orderid FROM temp_table2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to insert into SQL Server the syntax would be

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[YOURTABLE] SELECT * FROM [MATCHING_TABLE] WHERE CLAUSE
```

The caveat here is that the two tables must have identical schemas or you will have to explicitly define the columns.  Also this will not work properly for tables with identity columns